# User consistently tags his questions with wrong tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've just found a user which consistently uses wrong tags for his questions. As far as I have checked almost every of his 139 questions is tagged erroneously. For example:

- A [simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8222671/revisions) about Android emulator is tagged with [android-layout](/questions/tagged/android-layout), [android-ndk](/questions/tagged/android-ndk), [android-widget](/questions/tagged/android-widget) at the same time, while [question about layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7334751/648313) is tagged with [android-emulator](/questions/tagged/android-emulator).
- [Question about iPhone WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7170848/648313) is tagged with [iphone-sdk-4.0](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-4.0), [iphone-sdk-3.0](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk-3.0), [ios4](/questions/tagged/ios4), [cocos2d-iphone](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-iphone).

Now I wonder what should I do? So far I see several options:

1. Retag every question he ever tagged erroneously
2. Retag and notify the moderators about this user (by flagging one or several questions)
3. Just flag one of his questions for moderator attention to do batch retag (first remove all tags except base ones: [android](/questions/tagged/android), [ios](/questions/tagged/ios), then I can review his questions and add other tags where necessary).
4. Contact that user in some way (through comments or chat) and point him to the tagging guidelines.

I think the second option is preferable. Any thoughts?

Comment: Link, or it didn't happen.  There's no way to evaluate your claims unless we look at the user's profile.

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://stackoverflow.com/users/881635/idroid-explorer

Comment: I don't think you should go to the trouble of retagging every question. I'd let the OP do it. Do you want me to send him a moderator message?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I think that's a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Looks like it didn't make any effect on him. He fixed tags in only one question since than.